# Function on Small-Business Finance Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

i am struggling to make a spreadsheet which will help me take control of member's subscription fees. Fees are paid per month. I want to enter in M13 cell a function that will calculate the amount of money the member owes for Year 2013 based on current month (L1).

- In 2014 i entered "=100-SUM(A17:L17)", where 100=the total fees per year minus the sum of all the months. I don't want to see that someone owes 100 for 2014 even if we still have 2013!I want it to be calculated based on current month.
- Moreover, i want every unpaid month to have an auto-red-colored cell.

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: this is not a programming related question. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather simple task. I will show you how my spread sheet looks and then provide the formulas that I used:

[image]

D1: =MONTH(TODAY())

D2: =YEAR(TODAY())

N12: =IF(B10>D2,0,$D$1*$D$3-SUM(B12:M12))

and the formatting (for 2014) looks like this: 
[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable help! I have just finished the whole spreadsheet with success!
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A single rule in A5 `=AND($L$1>A4,ISBLANK(A5))` with Applied to `=$A$5:$L$5` and copied with Format Painter should be adequate, without any other changes.

*Oops - forgot the mention the other part:*

In M17: `=120-SUMIF(A16:L16,"<"&$L1,A17:L17)`